# What would be the proper solution to solve this function?

Tags: ms-access

Owner: IIf(isNull([Company]),[OwnerFirst] & ", " [OwnerLast],[Company])

You may have entered an invalid identifier or typed parenthesis following the Null constant

Comment: See whether you like [Nz()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) for this. `Nz([Company], [OwnerFirst] & ", " & [OwnerLast])`

Answer (score 2):

You need another ampersand operator before `[OwnerLast]`. Try-

```
=IIF(IsNull([Company]),[OwnerFirst] & ", " & [OwnerLast],[Company])
```